AWS EB Docker Linux 2 Failed Deployment
I am running a Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.8.1 on my AWS EB
When deploying my source it works if I simply upload my docker-compose.yml file, the upload works and the app is live.
I am trying to add the .ebextensions directory allowing me to use this to forwards log files to cloudwatch log groups.
In order to to do this I have this following directory

production

.ebextensions
docker-compose.yml



I then zip this up so I have a production.zip when I then try and deploy this zip file I get the following error.
Instance deployment: Both 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in your source bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment failed.
But it works perfectly file if I just upload the docker-compose.yml file.
Why can EB not find the docker-compose.yml file in the compressed zip?

If anyone faces this issue, the issue was due to the way I was compressing the files. I was compressing the production folder, I am using a MAC and instead I selected the inner files/folders (docker-compose.yml and .ebextensions) and compressed those and it works.
So basically don't compress the folder itself select all the files/folders and compress those!
